# Like TableView Display in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to display packages offer in android. Package will be dynamically. How can I divide it in rowspan and column span etc in Android? Please review attached screenshot and provide your valuable feedback for same.

[image: i want display content like below in Android. Everything is dynamic how can i device row and column. Any idea how can i implement it with smoothly.]

Comment: You can try TableView library.

Comment: i am working on it. But there is no option found for colspan and rowspan.